# Time variable is not numeric for survival analysing in maftools

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to run a survival analysis for 'TTN' gene within a liver cancer. I used the TCGAbiolinks package for downloading LIHC data. And to perform survival analysis this command was used:

```
mafSurvival(maf = laml, genes = 'TTN', time = 'days_to_last_followup', Status = 'Overall_Survival_Status', isTCGA = TRUE)
```

but It resulted in error "**Time variable is not numeric**"!

This is my code:

```
library(maftools)
library(TCGAbiolinks)
library(tidyverse)

maf <- GDCquery_Maf("LIHC", pipelines = "muse")


clin <- GDCquery_clinic("TCGA-LIHC","clinical")

my_data <- as_tibble(clin)

# get column names
col <- colnames(my_data)


# Rename column where names is "Sepal.Length"
names(my_data)[names(my_data) == "bcr_patient_barcode"] <- "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
names(my_data)[names(my_data) == "submitter_id"] <- "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
names(my_data)[names(my_data) == "vital_status"] <- "Overall_Survival_Status"

names(my_data)[names(my_data) == "Dead"] <- FALSE
names(my_data)[names(my_data) == "Alive"] <- TRUE


laml = read.maf(
  maf,
  clinicalData = my_data,
  removeDuplicatedVariants = TRUE,
  useAll = TRUE,
  gisticAllLesionsFile = NULL,
  gisticAmpGenesFile = NULL,
  gisticDelGenesFile = NULL,
  gisticScoresFile = NULL,
  cnLevel = "all",
  cnTable = NULL,
  isTCGA = FALSE,
  vc_nonSyn = NULL,
  verbose = TRUE
)

plotmafSummary(maf = laml, rmOutlier = TRUE, addStat = 'median', dashboard = TRUE, titvRaw = FALSE)

#oncoplot for top ten mutated genes.
oncoplot(maf = laml, top = 10)


#####################################Function_mafSurvival##################################


#Survival analysis based on grouping of Gene_name mutation status
mafSurvival(maf = laml, genes = 'TTN', time = 'days_to_last_followup', Status = 'Overall_Survival_Status', isTCGA = TRUE)
```

I would appreciate any help to make it suitable for the surival analysis using maftools and TCGAbiolinks packages.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `isTCGA=TRUE` in your call to `read.maf` (or truncate it in the maf (`maf$Tumor_Sample_Barcode <- substr(maf$Tumor_Sample_Barcode, 1, 12)`)).

The code below works:

```r
invisible(lapply(c("maftools", "TCGAbiolinks"), require, character.only=TRUE))  
maf <- GDCquery_Maf("LIHC", pipelines = "muse")
clin <- GDCquery_clinic("TCGA-LIHC","clinical")
my_data <- data.frame(clin, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
colnames(my_data)[colnames(my_data)=="submitter_id"] <-  "Tumor_Sample_Barcode"
colnames(my_data)[colnames(my_data)=="vital_status"] <-  "Overall_Survival_Status"

laml <- read.maf(maf, clinicalData = my_data, isTCGA = TRUE)
#> -Validating
#> -Silent variants: 18306 
#> -Summarizing
#> --Possible FLAGS among top ten genes:
#>   TTN
#>   MUC16
#>   OBSCN
#>   FLG
#> -Processing clinical data
#> -Finished in 3.409s elapsed (4.562s cpu)

mafSurvival(maf = laml, genes = 'TTN', time = 'days_to_last_follow_up', Status = 'Overall_Survival_Status', isTCGA = TRUE)
#> Looking for clinical data in annoatation slot of MAF..
#> Number of mutated samples for given genes:
#> TTN 
#>  79
#> Median survival..
#>     Group medianTime   N
#> 1: Mutant        495  79
#> 2:     WT        602 283
#> Removed 83 samples with NA's
#> Warning in survival::Surv(time = Time, event = Status): Invalid status value,
#> converted to NA

#> Warning in survival::Surv(time = Time, event = Status): Invalid status value,
#> converted to NA

#> Warning in survival::Surv(time = Time, event = Status): Invalid status value,
#> converted to NA
```

[image]